# Centreing a cluster of left-aligned data in a table column

Tags: css, alignment, html-table, padding, margins

I have a tables problem, for which I have not found any solution, be it HTML tables, CSS tables, HTML tables with CSS...  yet it seems like such a basic elementary requirement for well-rendered typesetting, I can't believe that in the 19 years since HTML went public (1996), we still don't have a markup standard that can do it!

The problem: Making table columns that have left-justified text, but with the header row text justified independently of the data rows below it.

The problem with the dirt-simple method of simply left-aligning the column contents is if the header is quite long (making the column quite wide), but all the data items are relatively short width, the table looks "goofy" with all the data hugging the left edge of this really wide column.  Visually, a "more centred" appearance is more pleasing.

BUT, the problem with centre-aligning the data is unless every single datum is exactly the same width (which obviously it won't be), it won't have the nice neat "visually clean" appearance of each datum consistently beginning at a common left margin!

So I tried making a table that uses 3 actual columns for one "visual column", with the following:

```
<table rules="groups">
<colgroup>
    <col>
    <col width="0*">
    <col>
</colgroup>
```

I then put the header text in a `<th colspan="3" align="center">`, while the data in subsequent rows is contained in a normal `<td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">` flanked by a blank "padding" `<td>` before it and after it.  (The `width="0*"` parameter of the middle `<col>` within the `<colgroup>` is what keeps the left-justified "data cluster" more-or-less centred in the visual column, by keeping the invisible column boundaries tight against the data.

This works for the most part, except it has two flaws:

1: Some browsers will try to make the entire colgroup as narrow as possible, line-wrapping long headers rather than allowing long headers to expand the width of the colgroup / "visual column" as necessary.

2: This table scheme unfortunately does not let data cells line-wrap.  So whenever the data is very long and would look better line-wrapped, the table just keeps expanding horizontally instead, introducing horizontal scroll bars and other uglyness.

If I remove the `nowrap="nowrap"` parameter from the `<td>` data cells to allow wrapping, the web browser forcefully wraps the text to keep the column as narrow as possible, even though I'd prefer the column to expand (up to a reasonable limit, until horozontal scroll bars would otherwise be necessary).

If I remove the `width="0*"` parameter from the `<col>` tag (so I can then remove the `nowrap="nowrap"` parameter from the `<td>` data cells), the middle actual-column becomes wider than it needs to be (wider than even the widest datum), causing the data cluster to no longer appear very centred in the visual column.

How to solve this?

```
<table rules="groups">
    <caption>This table still has a problem when data (not headers!) becomes extremely wide and would be better line-wrapped</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col width="0*">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col width="0*">
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" align="center">Very long heading text.  Should expand the column width instead of wrapping</th>
            <th colspan="3" align="center">&hellip;but some browsers unfortunately wrap these.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Short datum</td>  <td></td>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Col 2 datum 1</td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Long datum but still left-aligned in cluster</td>  <td></td>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Col 2 datum 2</td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Data cluster is still centred in visual column</td>  <td></td>
            <td></td>  <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">Col 2 datum 3</td>  <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: With such a long explanation you could have included the fiddle as well...

Comment: Sorry, not experienced enough yet with this site to know what fiddle is / how to use it.